# PWide Char and String Confusion in Delphi trying to send Email

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Program returns an error of, expected PWideChar instead of string

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  mailtoStr, subject, body : string;
begin
mailtostr := 'mailto:theirEmail@hotmail.com';
subject := '?Subject=Email Subject';
body :=  '&Body=Email Body';
ShellExecute(Self.Handle,
             nil,
             mailtostr +
             subject+
             body,
             nil,
             nil,
             SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

so I changed my code to ...

```
StringToWideChar('mailto:'+MailToStr+'?Subject=' + edSubject.Text+'&Body=' + edBody.Text, MailToWideChar, Length('mailto:'+MailToStr+'?Subject=' + edSubject.Text+'&Body=' + edBody.Text));
```

in otherwords put it all on one line and changed the rest of the procedure to...

```
ShellExecute(Self.Handle,
             nil,
             MailToWideChar,
             nil,
             nil,
             SW_NORMAL);
```

But getting a run-time exception error at the StringToWideCharLine :S

..any idea why?

Comment: StringToWideChar is absolutely not what you need here. It does something completely different. Forget all about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to put the string inside `PChar()` to 'cast' it to a `PChar`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  mailtoStr, subject, body: string;
begin
  mailtostr := 'mailto:theirEmail@hotmail.com';
  subject := '?Subject=Email Subject';
  body := '&Body=Email Body';
  ShellExecute(Self.Handle,
               nil,
               PChar(mailtoStr + subject + body),
               nil,
               nil,
               SW_NORMAL);
end;
```

Comment: Thankyou!! This site is so great, everyone is so helpful and i spent ages trying to figure that out :L live and learn! :D